# HTML from external file in MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a client that is requesting an area be built on the stage of an existing .fla file (that I built as well) that loads html content from an external file. This area will serve as a dynamic ad banner that displays the contents of the external file. Ideally, the external file would contain links to different .html files that can easily be edited as the content needs change.

I have tried HTMLloader, but I am limited to a .swf file only and cannot use AIR.

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're contradicting yourself.  You state you need to load 'html content from an external file' and then say that you are 'limited to a .swf'. Which is it? Is the HTML content being stored in html files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact needing to pull content from an external .html file, the following code showcases how to load external html content. In my example, I stored some content in a file named 'MyBannerAd.html', but you can point it to wherever you want and whatever filename you wish.  Once the file has loaded, the `externalFileLoadComplete` function is called at which time I created a textfield and stored the contents of the file that was loaded from the external file as the `htmlText` property of the TextField. If you already have a textfield created, you can simply reference that one instead.  The code shown below executed successfully using Flash CC 2014.

```
import flash.text.TextField;

function externalFileLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
    myTextField.htmlText = e.target.data;
    addChild(myTextField);
}

var fileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("MyBannerAd.html");

fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, externalFileLoadComplete);
fileLoader.load(fileRequest);
```